# How to iterate through all levels of a xml/json/dict in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following xml response from an API endpoint:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events>
    <eventData>
        <eventID>32669037</eventID>
        <userID>
            <loginID>userone</loginID>
            <userDN>cn=userone,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=users,dc=com</userDN>
        </userID>
        <type>Logout</type>
        <ipAddress>1.2.3.4</ipAddress>
        <status>success</status>
        <accessTime>2022-12-04T09:56:39.678Z</accessTime>
        <ECID>abcdefgh</ECID>
        <attributeMap>
            <attribute>
                <key>User-Agent</key>
                <value>Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CasperJS/1.1.3+PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributeMap>
    </eventData>
    <eventData>
        <eventID>62669036</eventID>
        <userID>
            <loginID>usertwo</loginID>
            <userDN>cn=usertwo,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=users,dc=com</userDN>
        </userID>
        <type>CredentialValidation</type>
        <ipAddress>5.6.7.8</ipAddress>
        <status>success</status>
        <accessTime>2022-12-04T09:53:06.779Z</accessTime>
        <ECID>adfxx^^sfdffd</ECID>
        <attributeMap>
            <attribute>
                <key>User-Agent</key>
                <value>Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CasperJS/1.1.3+PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributeMap>
    </eventData>
</Events>
```

`

My goal is to flatten each 'eventData' into a single row to load into a table, so the above snippet is 2 rows.

I've tried xmltodict and iterate through the dictionary but I cannot get the 'lower level' values. Same happens with json.dumps and .loads after.
Similar with converting to a dataframe, cant seem to be able to use a for loop to go through the entire thing and access the lower member values at the same time.

How can I achieve this?

Everytime I try a for loop on the different object types, it seems im always at the highest level (Events)

Also if I try to read the values, e.g. print(['Events']['eventData'][0]['eventID']) or accessing the lower level members, I can iterate but i cant properly define a range to loop through [0]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `beautifulsoup` to parse the XML document into a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events>
    <eventData>
        <eventID>32669037</eventID>
        <userID>
            <loginID>userone</loginID>
            <userDN>cn=userone,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=users,dc=com</userDN>
        </userID>
        <type>Logout</type>
        <ipAddress>1.2.3.4</ipAddress>
        <status>success</status>
        <accessTime>2022-12-04T09:56:39.678Z</accessTime>
        <ECID>abcdefgh</ECID>
        <attributeMap>
            <attribute>
                <key>User-Agent</key>
                <value>Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CasperJS/1.1.3+PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributeMap>
    </eventData>
    <eventData>
        <eventID>62669036</eventID>
        <userID>
            <loginID>usertwo</loginID>
            <userDN>cn=usertwo,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=users,dc=com</userDN>
        </userID>
        <type>CredentialValidation</type>
        <ipAddress>5.6.7.8</ipAddress>
        <status>success</status>
        <accessTime>2022-12-04T09:53:06.779Z</accessTime>
        <ECID>adfxx^^sfdffd</ECID>
        <attributeMap>
            <attribute>
                <key>User-Agent</key>
                <value>Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CasperJS/1.1.3+PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributeMap>
    </eventData>
</Events>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            t.name: tmp
            if len(tmp := t.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")) > 1
            else tmp[0]
            for t in d.find_all(recursive=False)
        }
        for d in soup.find_all("eventData")
    ]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    eventID                                                userID                  type ipAddress   status                accessTime           ECID                                                                                                                         attributeMap
0  32669037  [userone, cn=userone,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=users,dc=com]                Logout   1.2.3.4  success  2022-12-04T09:56:39.678Z       abcdefgh  [User-Agent, Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CasperJS/1.1.3+PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1]
1  62669036  [usertwo, cn=usertwo,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=users,dc=com]  CredentialValidation   5.6.7.8  success  2022-12-04T09:53:06.779Z  adfxx^^sfdffd  [User-Agent, Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CasperJS/1.1.3+PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty well however the 'child' records are not individual columns. Would you mind explaining how this is achieving the child record so I can try to split it? Recursive=True will do the trick but its 'duplicating' the value